# ZonedDateTime retrieved with one hour shift in Hsqldb with 2.6.x

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hsqldb, zoneddatetime

I use Spring boot and JPA and my Order domain object have this field:

```
@Column(name = "TIMESTAMP")
private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
```

I create a date with this method:

```
protected static ZonedDateTime createZonedDateTime(final String date) {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date + " 00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
    return ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

When I insert this in database throw JPA, with showsql to true, I can see that the inserted date is: `[2020-01-01T00:00+01:00[Europe/Paris]]`

when I retrieve the data throw JPA repository, the date I get is: `2020-01-01T01:00+01:00[Europe/Paris]`

How come I have one hour shift? It's not working since hsqldb `2.6.0`. Works perfectly with `2.5.0`.

I use Liquidbase to create the field with:

```
<column name="TIMESTAMP" type="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"
                remarks="The timestamp of the order"/>
```

Comment: Seems i don't succeed to make hsqldb insert script (throw liquidbase) have the same timezone than my tests

Comment: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is equivalent to OffsetDateTime. I don't know how the JPA is converting the values back from OffsetDateTime to ZonedDateTime, but it cannot be done correctly without the zone offset and zone name matching for the given timestamp.